# UPDATE values of a column in a table with Python in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I want to update a column with SQL server query in python, as you see I am updating the relative column as below:
I have a CSV file with some A values of relative table as below:

CSV file: (a.csv)

```
ART-B-C-ART0015-D-E01
ADC-B-C-ADC00112-V-E01
```

Python Code: (create Name Value)

```
ff = pd.read_csv("C:\\a.csv",encoding='cp1252')
ff["Name"]= df["A"].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4,5})') + "-A"
```

Result of python Code:

```
ART0015-A
ADC00112-A
```

Table :

```
A                              Name                     FamilyName
ART-B-C-ART0015-D-E01          NULL                        ART
ADC-B-C-ADC00112-V-E01         NULL                      ADC00112
```

Also A is a column in my table (Not all of the A records but some of them) and based on A value I want to update Name column.
My database is SQL Server and I don't know how to update in  Name Column in SQL Server where the A value in the csv file is equal to A in the relative table.
Code in Python:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server}; Server=ipaddress; Database=dbname; UID=username; PWD= {password};')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()
for row in ff.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE database.dbo.tablename SET Name where ?

)

conn.commit()
```

Expected result in table

```
A                              Name                     FamilyName
ART-B-C-ART0015-D-E01          ART0015-A                 ART
ADC-B-C-ADC00112-V-E01         ADC00112-A                ADC00112
```

Comment: *I have a CSV file with A value in the column* Does this file is available for MySQL server access? Show complete table's CREATE TABLE, some data sample for a table (3-5 rows) and for CSV file (2-3 rows), and desired result (table content after update). Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I updated my content. but please be informed that i am not creating a table. I have a table and i must update a specific column.

Comment: *please be informed that i am not creating a table.* But this table exists, so it has a structure which may be provided.

Comment: I shared the Table structure too/

Comment: Does initial table example shows its current state? if so then the data for table updating and `Name` values set is already available in a table, and you do not need in your SCV at all.

Comment: PS. The tablename in shown code is `database.dbo.tablename` which matches SQL Server (MS SQL) dialect, not MySQL. Please look carefully what DB server you deal with.

Comment: No , I have a csv file with some A values, I am going to modify the A value and put it in the Name value. this is an example. imagine my table has 10000 rows and in the csv file only 100 A value has been specified so i use regex to get my expected string and put it in Name value. I dont know how to put updated Name value in the table.\

Comment: Please read one more - "Show complete table's CREATE TABLE, some data sample for a table (3-5 rows) and for CSV file (2-3 rows), and desired result (table content after update)". You must show what data you have initially, what values are provided in the file, and what values they are combined into. We must see and understand the algorithm of matching and transformation. Now I cannot find the difference between `table.A` values and CSV file data - so I cannot find the reason to use the file at all.

Comment: *A value has been specified so i use regex to get my expected string and put it in Name value.* Provide the value from the file to MySQL as-is - it may extract needed part and construct needed name by more easy way.

Comment: My mistake was about mysql.this is sql server. I tried my best to update the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an SQL temp table and inner join to update the values. This will work for only updating a subset of records in your SQL table. It can also be efficient at updating many records.

### SQL Cursor

```py
# reduce number of calls to server on inserts
cursor.fast_executemany = True
```

### Create Temporary Table

```
statement = "CREATE TABLE #temp_tablename(A VARCHAR(200), Name VARCHAR(200))"
cursor.execute(statement)
```

### Insert Values into a Temporary Table

```py
# insert only the key and the updated values
subset = ff[['A','Name']]

# form SQL insert statement
columns = ", ".join(subset.columns)
values = '('+', '.join(['?']*len(subset.columns))+')'

# insert
statement = "INSERT INTO #temp_tablename ("+columns+") VALUES "+values
insert = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]

cursor.executemany(statement, insert)
```

### Update Values in Main Table from Temporary Table

```py
statement = '''
UPDATE
     tablename
SET
     u.Name
FROM
     tablename AS t
INNER JOIN 
     #temp_tablename AS u 
ON
     u.A=t.A;
'''

cursor.execute(statement)
```

### Drop Temporary Table

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE #temp_tablename")
```

Comment: Dear Jason. Thanks. isnt any way to just use  UPDATE database.dbo.tablename query and not creating a temp table?

Comment: You could but I image it would require creating the syntax in a Python loop due to needing an SQL case statement. I think this would also be the most efficient approach to take.